# Structure of the functional space $\int_ {- \infty} ^ \infty f (x) dx = 1 $

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-distributions, special-functions, improper-integrals, fourier-series

Please, help me with studying of useful practical features of the following functional space:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx = 1$$
For example:

1) What basis types are most convenient for representation an element from the space?

2) How to find an element of best approximation for the given data set $\{(x_i, y_i) | i = \overline{1,n} \}$?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDistribution.html may see this

Comment: Gauss distribution is in that class of function. In particular, all continous distributions in probability theory are from that type!

Comment: If the function has a Fourier transform F(k) then it is equal to a constant times F(0).

Comment: @Urgje reality check: $f(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}2}$

Comment: This is the set of all normalized, nonzero σ-finite measures and signed measures of ℝ. It has all the probability distributions but also has stuff that gets negative.

Comment: @AlexR I do not understand your remark. The Fourier transform is F(k)={1/(√(2π)}∫dxexp[ikx]f(x), so F(0)={1/(√(2π)}∫dxf(x) and ∫dxf(x)={√(2π)}F(0).

Comment: @Urgje the fourier transform of the function I specified is the function itself, clearly not constant.

Comment: @AlexR It is not the function but the integral ∫dxexp[ikx]f(x) taken in k=0, i.e., ∫dxf(x) that I am talking about.

Comment: @Urgje Your sentence claims that the fourier transform of a function $f$ with $\int_{\mathbb R} f = 1$ is a constant? What exactly did you want to say? It seems to me I have misunderstood.

Comment: @AlexR It is really simple. The Fourier transform F(k) of a function f(x) taken in k=0 is proportional to ∫dxf(x). That's all.

Comment: I don't understand part 2). Surely you can run a function through given points $(x_i,y_i)$ and have it have integral equal to $1$. How do you measure the "quality", what does the "best" mean?

Comment: @127.0.9.6 Kriging, e.g., gives us pretty good quality measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral condition says very little about $f$; it selects an affine subspace of codimension $1$, which is not any more manageable than the space you began with. For any  $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, the function $$f-c\chi_{[0,1]},\quad \text{where } c = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f -1 $$ satisfies your condition. So, if you have a convenient representation here, you have it for all $L^1(\mathbb R)$.

The [Haar system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet) is a convenient basis for  the linear space $\{f\in L^1(\mathbb R):\int_{-\infty}^\infty f=0\}$. Therefore, every function in your space can be written as 
$$f = \chi_{[0,1]}+ \sum_{n,k}c_{n,k} \psi_{n,k}$$ 
with $\psi_{n,k}$ being Haar functions. You can find $c_{n,k}$ using the fact that the Haar system is orthogonal in $L^2$ (even though your function need not be in $L^2$): $c_{n,k} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f\psi_{n,k} $.